# How can I open or review a large txt file

Tags: data-warehouse, notepad

I have a few large txt files I'm trying to load into a data warehouse, I do get an error message with the offending row/line number but cannot open the txt file to review it as says it's 2 large 2,413,060KB. Someone suggested using the cmd option to do this but unsure how.

Comment: Is using notepad obligatory? What about vim?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use **[HJSplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/windows/)** in order to split the data or using another vim-based program such as [gVim](http://www.vim.org/download.php). Also it may be good to free up your PC's RAM as much as possible.